# Slow internet cable speed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, internet, download-speed

When I take a speed test, I get 80 mb/s, when I try download something, I only get about 5 mb/s. I saw a lot of questions about wifi but none about ethernet.

Comment: Try a different cable and compare results.

Comment: What are you trying to download? Have you considered that the server or the path might limit the speed (see [Bottleneck](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/bottleneck))?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/speetest is a reliable speed test. What does it say before and after you change Ethernet patch cords? Also cycle the power on that cable modem, with at least 120 seconds off before you power back up. Please click [edit] and post the results in your original question.